# Efficient way to reduce length of mongo array subdocuments on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, projection

I need a way to reduce the length of mongo subdocuments on mongoose.

I have a schema like this:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    field1: {
        type: String
    },
    subdocuments: {
        prop1: [{x:String,y:Number}],
        prop2: [{x:String,y:Number}]
    }
});
```

then I use a find from a model that uses this schema passing also the projection fields.

The problem is that prop1 and prop2 are very big arrays (around 1000 elements) so I need only the first n of those sorted by y.

Do you know an efficient way to get only the subdocuments I need?

Maybe it is better to use an aggregate function? And in this case how it works the projection to get only the fields I really need?

Many thanks in advance.
d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to do it through [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), concate the `prop1` array with `prop2` array to `prop` array through `$concatArrays`, after unwinding the `prop` array, sort by `y` value, eventually `$limit` the first `n` element.

```
var n = 6;
Document.aggregate([
         {$project: {
               prop: {$concatArrays: ['$sudocuments.prop1', 
                                      '$sudocuments.prop2']}}},
         {$unwind: '$prop'},
         {$sort: {'prop.y': 1}}, 
         {$limit: n}
  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
model.find({/* query */})
  .slice('subdocuments.prop1', [/* skip */, /* limit */])
  .exec(/*callback*/);
```

or

```
model.find({/* query */})
  .where('subdocuments.prop1').slice(/* limit */)
```

Mongoose slice: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-slice